# Retrieve type alias alternate name using reflection

Tags: go

Is it possible in any form or fashion to retrieve the name of a type alias? I realize that this is likely impossible because a type alias IS the same type, and indeed something such as the following definitely prints the original type.

```
type MyString string
type AliasString = MyString
var a AliasString = "hello"
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(a).Type().Name())
// prints MyString
```

Is there ANY way for this to be able to print `AliasString`? Or is there just absolutely no way to distinguish them as an alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [proposal](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/18130-type-alias.md#reflect), type aliases are mostly invisible at runtime. The exception is in the name of embedded fields.

With the types in the question, there's no way to distinguish the alias from the original type.

Comment: I figured as much, as I did read through the whole proposal and specification of aliases. Figured it couldn't hurt to ask though in the hopes that there is some sort of accessable metadata attached to them.